# How to navigate to another page with preselected value without query params JS

Tags: javascript, url

I have a question. I'm working on website written in pure JS. I have a button on homepage **mypage.com** and when I click on it, it navigates to another page **mypage.com/list**. The button is just a simple **a** tag with href attr.

A client want me to do **mypage.com/list** with preselected option, but the url doesn't contain query params. My select component has a few options and when I click on an option I fetch some data from external API based on an url. Both **mypage.com/list** is the same all the time, when I change the options.

I need navigate to **mypage.com/list**, and save info with a **value = option1**.

It is simple image that shows how it is now and how it must be.
[image]

Do you know how to solve it? How to redirect with preselected option without params? Is a place when could I store info about a picked option? localStorage maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The option I see if you're not using a state handler in the app is `localStorage`:

```
In mypage.com
// Create a key-value
localStorage.setItem('option', 'value');

In mypage.com/list
// Get value
let value = localStorage.getItem('option');
```